# JBehave - run a single scenario

Tags: java, jbehave

My situation is this:

I have a JBehave story containing multiple Scenarios. Each scenario writes some files, checks that they're as expected. Then the `@BeforeScenario` for the next scenario causes the framework to delete the output files.

When some scenario is failing, I want to run just that scenario in isolation -- so I can conveniently examine the output file before it is deleted (and also for speed). Other people have asked the same question, and have been told "use Meta Filtering" - http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html - which seems to be the right tool.

But I don't want to go to the effort of annotating every other scenario with `@skip`. I'd like to annotate just one scenario with `@wip`, and run just that test.

I tried this:

```
Narrative:
An example story

Scenario: A scenario I don't want to run this time
Given foo
When bar
Then baz

Meta: @wip
Scenario: A scenario that is work in progress
Given foo
When bar
Then baz
```

... which I then run with an `Embedder` configured thus:

```
embedder.useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+wip"));
```

This causes the whole story to be skipped, because the story doesn't match:

```
1 stories excluded by filter: +wip
```

However, if I annotate the *story* with `@wip`, then both scenarios are run, because both inherit the `wip` meta property.

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Comment: I have [scenario filtering](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html) working by matching on scenario tags and filtering on the value. e.g. "Meta: @scenario wip" and embedder.useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+scenario wip")). But before you try custom tag-values, you should switch the order of your Scenario and Meta tags to follow jBehave grammar

Comment: That could well be it!

Comment: Yep. Tried it out, and your comment became my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is simply that your `Meta:` declaration belongs *below* the `Scenario:` header.

So:

```
Scenario: A scenario that is work in progress
Meta: @wip
Given foo
When bar
Then baz
```

Now `embedder.useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+wip"));` will achieve what you want.